# Django Calculate Similar Posts Based On Categories Not Working

Tags: django, categories, similarity

I want to calculate similar posts based on categories. This is what I have so far in models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=15)

    def get_related_posts_by_tags(self):
       category = get_object_or_404(Category, name=self.category.title)
       posts = Post.objects.filter(category=category)
       return posts

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
```

And in my templates:

```
{% for posts in object.get_related_post_by_tag %}
   {{ posts.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

For whatever reason, this does not work, and in my template, I do not seen any posts with the same category. This is why I am wonder if I am doing it wrong, or if I have little problem I easily fix. Thanks for all help.

Comment: Does you `Category` have a `title` or a `name`, because you use `self.category.title`, but your `Category` seems to have only a `name` field.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem wait I know the problem; in his models he says 'object.get_related_post_by_tags' and in his template he says 'object.get_related_post_by_tag'

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it has only name field.

Comment: @JohnD9oe: yes, but still this will require extra queries, so it is not very efficient. You will make a query with `self.category`, and then another one with the `get_objects_or_404` to retrieve the *same* category again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=15)

    def get_related_posts_by_tags(self):
       return Post.objects.filter(category_id=self.category_id)
```

This will also prevent loading the `Category` object in memory if it is not used later on.

You might want to exclude the current post, in that case, you can use:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=15)

    def get_related_posts_by_tags(self):
       return Post.objects.filter(
           category_id=self.category_id
        ).exclude(pk=self.pk)
```

In your template there is also a typo: it is `get_related_posts_by_tags`, so `_posts_`, not <s>`_post_`</s>

```
{% for posts in object.get_related_posts_by_tags %}
   {{ posts.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi your answer worked but `.exclude(pk=self.pk)` did not work. It showed same post in the recommendation place.

Comment: @Xandier: are you sure you did not `return` the filtered queryset, and then have a `.exclude(..)` call? Normally if the `.exclude(..)` call is in the *chain* of the `QuerySet` method calls, it will exclude the current post.

Comment: no I returned filtered query set with `.exclude(pk=self.pk)`. I did this: `return Post.objects.filter(category_id=self.category_id).exclude(pk=self.pk)`

Comment: @Xandier: can you `print(self.pk)` for the return line. Are you sure you did not make two posts with the same title, etc.

Comment: @Williem Van Onsem, No I am sure they do not have same title, and when you do print(self.pk) I get 74 for one post. When I try the other post it is 1.

Comment: @Xandier: so what happens if you render `{{ object.pk }}` and then in the for loop `{{ posts.pk }}`?

Comment: @Williem Van Onsem, wait I fix it. now it work perfect. thanks for help.     :)